# Cucumber with Qt/QML

Tags: qt, qml, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-cpp

Is there a way to use [Cucumber](https://github.com/cucumber) with [Qt/QML](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qtqml-index.html)? and if there's some examples, i would appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: why not explain what is Cucumber?

Comment: I thought the link does it well, it's a tool that supports Behaviour-Driven Development (BDD).

Comment: i think you should use [squish](https://www.froglogic.com/squish/features/bdd-behavior-driven-development-testing/)

Comment: thanks, I'll check it out!

Comment: @MahdiKhalili if you can add your comment as a response, i would accept it as a response, because after all the wait, i think squish is the most close answer to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should use [Squish](https://www.froglogic.com/squish/features/bdd-behavior-driven-development-testing/)
:)

Comment: Well, as soon as I have $302 each month just for testing my private Qt repos, I will do so. 
A much better appraoch imho: how can I use Cucumber / Gherkin with QtTest modules?